# Localization not working on NullText attribute of ASPxTextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, localization, devexpress

In my application I have some `TextBox` with `NullText` attribute. I want when I change language then `NullText` must be change according to selected language.

```
<dx:ASPxLabel ID="lbllastName" runat="server"  Text="Last Name" 
              meta:resourcekey="LastnameResource1">
</dx:ASPxLabel>

<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtlastName" runat="server" NullText="Last Name"
                meta:resourcekey="LastnameResource1" >
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

Now when I change language from English to danish then  label show  **"Efternavn"** but  `NullText` still show **"Last Name"**

Comment: It seems that you need to read the `NullText` property also from the *Resources*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have to set the `NullText` property on  that  `Resources` label in  `Resources` file something like this -

> In your resource file

```
EnterYourEmailId.NullText
```